# Is there a way to list all nodejs function execution time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to measure execution time of nodejs functions recursively? `console.time` and `performance.mark` can only get the total time, but what I want is to list all inner function's time, like this way:

```js
function A() {
  B();
  C();
}
function B() {
  ...
}
function C() {
  ...
}

// some tool like timeit
timeit('A')
A();
timeit('A')
```

I wanna get the result like below:

```
A: 1000ms
- B: 400ms
- C: 600ms
```

and if there's any extensions in vscode can do it will be better, like in chrome we can see React Profiler

[An Example of React Profiler to list all components execution time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjMN6.png)

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Node.js Profiler that can do that. You can find more information here https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/

Also, it is possible to load the profiler output to Chrome to see nice visualization of the profiling data.

Apart from that, you could create a flame chart to analyze your application execution, for example here is a good guide https://betterprogramming.pub/create-a-flame-graph-for-your-node-app-profiling-nodejs-app-e0a91e5ed585